# Mapping not found in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

For the last couple of days, I checked out articles on stackoverflow for my problem about configuration Spring unsuccessfully. 
When I request my url "/republicanos-web/main/index" the Dispatcher Servlet resolve my request for my controller, as should be. The return of my function on Controller call the dispatcher servlet again, returning 404 for me, because there's no mapping, only the HTML file. 
Mostly of the articles was talking about the parameter url-pattern on Dispatcher Servlet, alerting to use '/', instead of '/*', but in my code the url-pattern is correct: '/'. See my code:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>republicanos</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>republicanos</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>republicanos</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/republicanos-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
               org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**republicanos-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wearedevelopers.*" />

<bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>
```

**MainController.java**

```
package com.wearedevelopers.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String paginaInicial(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("mensagem", "Mensagem");
        return "/home";
    }
}
```

**My HTML file** is defined on webapp/WEB-INF/templates/home.html

On resume, my servlet is always trying to find a controller for my views, even if its returned by controller. A example on console log is:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/republicanos-web/home] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'republicanos'

Edit:
By the way, the server is tomcat.
Anyone could help?

Comment: Add your component base package like this, `<context:component-scan base-package="com.wearedevelopers" />`

Comment: what happens when you try `return "home";` ?

Comment: @VigNesh Thank you for your answear, it didn't work.

Comment: @BrianClozel return a 404. The console log show the message: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/republicanos-web/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'republicanos'

Comment: though answer is late but you can try                                                            return "templates/home";                                                                                               return "/templates/home";